# Itemize inside of a vwcol

Tags: enumitem

I am trying to create a multiple column environment with variable column width for use in a "Skills" section of my resume. However, I would also like to be able to itemize inside of this environment.

I can do things like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicol}{4}
\begin{itemize}
\item foo1
\item foo2
\item foo3
\item foo4
\end{itemize}
\end{multicol}

\end{document}
```

However, this gives me no control over column width, and my "Skills" section has parts that are naturally wider than others.

I've tried using the `vwcol` package, but unless I'm doing something terribly wrong, it seems to not work with embedded `enumitem` instances of `enumerate`. That is, things like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{vwcol}

\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.15,0.15,0.4,0.15}, sep=0.03]
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt]
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\(\cdot\)}
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item{This is a longer item that should be in a wider column, %
  and here it is continuing to be even longer}
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\end{itemize}
\end{vwcol}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error message while compiling using `pdflatex`:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
...
...
Underfull \vbox (badness 4954) detected at line 110

Overfull \hbox (1041.67691pt too wide) detected at line 110
[] []|[] [] []|[] [] []|[]
```

The resulting pdf had the first column present. The second column starts outside the margins.

I'm fairly new to LaTeX, and am not sure if there is other info I should be providing. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Yours is a very good first question. Only please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you sure it is columns, and not tables you are searching for. In columns the text is flowing freely from column 1 to column 2.

Comment: I switched to tables, and things worked immediately. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments

Comment: Rather than close the question, shouldn't an answer be made with the content from the comments? I don't understand why this question was closed.