# Itemize inside a vwcol

Tags: itemize, vwcol

If I use vwcol with just text, the columns work fine

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{vwcol}

\begin{document}
\begin{vwcol}[widths={.5,.5}, sep=.8cm, justify=flush]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque mauris purus, rhoncus in scelerisque vitae, viverra ac quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus\footnote{et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas}. Duis in ligula sed massa aliquam accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nec lectus sit amet turpis pellentesque posuere vel a lorem. Pellentesque laoreet nisl eu justo varius, quis pharetra ligula iaculis. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque mauris purus, rhoncus in scelerisque vitae, viverra ac quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus\footnote{et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas}. Duis in ligula sed massa aliquam accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nec lectus sit amet turpis pellentesque posuere vel a lorem. Pellentesque laoreet nisl eu justo varius, quis pharetra ligula iaculis. 
\end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```

But if I add an itemize in the middle of the text, then the second column gets pushed out of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{vwcol}

\begin{document}
\begin{vwcol}[widths={.5,.5}, sep=.8cm, justify=flush]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque mauris purus, rhoncus in scelerisque vitae, viverra ac quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus\footnote{et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas}. Duis in ligula sed massa aliquam accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nec lectus sit amet turpis pellentesque posuere vel a lorem. Pellentesque laoreet nisl eu justo varius, quis pharetra ligula iaculis. 
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque mauris purus, rhoncus in scelerisque vitae, viverra ac quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus\footnote{et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas}. Duis in ligula sed massa aliquam accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nec lectus sit amet turpis pellentesque posuere vel a lorem. Pellentesque laoreet nisl eu justo varius, quis pharetra ligula iaculis. 
\end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```

How can I have an itemize environment within a vwcol environment?

Contrary to the question [Itemize inside of a vwcol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380744/itemize-inside-of-a-vwcol), I don't want a table. Let the text flow between the columns!

Comment: the very first paragraph of the vwcol documentation says "Due to difﬁculties with the processing of such a thing, little else besides text is allowed within" . Especially latex lists which also use the parshape internally I see little chance of making them work with this package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is little chance of making a latex list work in `vwcol` you could do the bullets by hand as in

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{vwcol}

\begin{document}
\begin{vwcol}[widths={.5,.5}, sep=.8cm, justify=flush]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque mauris purus, rhoncus in scelerisque vitae, viverra ac quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus\footnote{et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas}. Duis in ligula sed massa aliquam accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nec lectus sit amet turpis pellentesque posuere vel a lorem. Pellentesque laoreet nisl eu justo varius, quis pharetra ligula iaculis. 

\textbullet\ A

\textbullet\ B

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque mauris purus, rhoncus in scelerisque vitae, viverra ac quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus\footnote{et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas}. Duis in ligula sed massa aliquam accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nec lectus sit amet turpis pellentesque posuere vel a lorem. Pellentesque laoreet nisl eu justo varius, quis pharetra ligula iaculis. 
\end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```

However all the complication of `vwcol` and the reason it can't support lists is to support having columns of different widths. As you are specifying two equal width columns you could use `multicol` instead,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque mauris purus, rhoncus in scelerisque vitae, viverra ac quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus\footnote{et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas}. Duis in ligula sed massa aliquam accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nec lectus sit amet turpis pellentesque posuere vel a lorem. Pellentesque laoreet nisl eu justo varius, quis pharetra ligula iaculis. 
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque mauris purus, rhoncus in scelerisque vitae, viverra ac quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus\footnote{et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas}. Duis in ligula sed massa aliquam accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nec lectus sit amet turpis pellentesque posuere vel a lorem. Pellentesque laoreet nisl eu justo varius, quis pharetra ligula iaculis. 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```